# Intrinsically disordered protein

Tags: 3d-structure, structural-biology

*This question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9477217/)*

The position that I have to visualize is in the 2700 position and this position exists in two ranges in https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q12802#family_and_domains the first range is Interaction with ESR1 and the second region is disordered, the first question is which range I should be based on? and the second is Why **intrinsically disordered protein(IDP)** can't be visualized in 3D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking how to visualise the disordered region of a protein is a bit like asking how to visualise the location of an electron.

An *intrinsically disordered protein*, by definition, has regions that are disordered. In other words, their location is variable under observation, so they cannot be precisely placed in a 3D model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @gringer, I understood.